# prefer table 3 over table 2 and table 2 over table 1

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables with names and number of few of my friends.

Table 3 has correct data, table 2 has minute errors in data and  table 1 has more than table 2.

if a user exists in table 2 and 3 then show table 3 details in output else table 2 details, if user is not even there in table 2 then show user data from table1.

more like a preference order.

**DUMMY DATA:**

```
table 1 :

name phone
abc   2343
bcd   3434
ccd   3455
ffc   4545

table 2 :

name phone
abc   2313
bcd   3414
ccd   3415


table 3 :

name phone
abc   2344
bcd   3431
```

expected output :

```
name phone
abc   2344
bcd   3431
ccd   3415
ffc   4545
```

I tried this query but unable to find correct output.

```
select phone,
    coalesce(table1.name, TABLE2.name,TABLE3.name) as namee
FROM   TABLE1
       left JOIN TABLE2 
               ON table1.name = table2.name
       INNER JOIN table3
               ON table3.name = table2.name
```

Would be a huge, huge heeelppppp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gordon was close; he had the preference backwards. Please make sure you understand *why* the script works.

```
-- grab all our preferred data first
select t3.*
from table3 t3

union all

-- grab anything that doesn't exist in our preferred table
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where not exists (select 1 from table3 t3 where t3.name = t2.name)

union all

-- grab anything that doesn't exist in our preferred tables
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.name = t1.name) and
      not exists (select 1 from table3 t3 where t3.name = t1.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `union all`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
union all
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.name = t2.name)
union all
select t3.*
from table3 t3
where not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.name = t3.name) and
      not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.name = t3.name);
```

Comment: Gives wrong output, I am getting "abc" from table 1 rather than from table 3

Comment: and getting "bcd" from table 2 rather than from table 3

Comment: @yono . . . If your ordering is table1 --> table 3 --> table 2 then just swap the table names.